# How to draw "square" dots instead of "round" dots with python 3 turtle?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I have this script:

```
import turtle
from math import sqrt
def isPrime(n):
    if n < 2: return False
    if n == 2: return True
    if n % 2 == 0: return False
    k = 3
    while k < sqrt(n):
        if n % k == 0:
            return False
        k += 2
    return True

def plot(k):
    numPrimes = 0
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.pencolor("green")
    turtle.dot(5)
    n= 1
    dir = 1
    for i in range(80):
        for j in range(n):
            turtle.setx(turtle.xcor() + 7*dir)
            if isPrime(k):
                numPrimes += 1
                turtle.pencolor("red")
            else:
                turtle.pencolor("black")
            turtle.dot(5)
            k += 1
        for j in range(n):
            turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() + 7*dir)
            if isPrime(k):
                turtle.pencolor("red")
                numPrimes += 1
            else:
                turtle.pencolor("black")
            turtle.dot(5)
            k += 1
        n += 1
        dir = -dir
    print(k-1, numPrimes)
    turtle.hideturtle()

plot(1)
```

It will draw rounded dots on the pane, but I want to draw "squared" dots (stamps?) that touch each other so there is no white space between the dots, and the dots themselves are not round, but square.

Basically it should look like a massive chessboard after, instead of a "pane with dots"

This is what it produces now
[image]

I want this [image]
(never mind the inaccuracy in this last screenshot of primes and non-prime, it is just to visualise what I mean by "square dots without white space"

How would I achieve this?
There seems to be no dot() in turtle that produces square stamps instead of round dots.

Comment: Have you tried using `turtle.shape('square')`?

Comment: Yes, that does not draw anything (well, it seems to try to draw something but the pen just goes in circles on the same spot. Note: I just swapped `turtle.dot(5)` for `turtle.shape('square')`
The result is a "spinning in place" turtle drawer

Comment: Also note, I do not want this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/draw-chess-board-using-turtle-in-python/. I would like to really print a 1px square "square dot" so to save time drawing _and_ avoid big squares that need to be filled with `pen.fillcolor`. It really should be a "substitute" for dot() making a square instead...

Comment: I wonder if I am better off using `PIL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've searched through turtle documentation and I didn't found anything that can make dots squared.
However, there is a method called `.stamp()` and it copies the turtle shape onto the canvas at the current turtle position.

So, my suggestion for you is:

1. to make a turtle square-shaped by `turtle.shape("square")`;
2. resize it using `turtle.turtlesize()` with `stretch_wid=` and `stretch_len=` args until you happy with it;
3. use `turtle.stamp()` instead of `turtle.dot()`

In your case I've also added a constant for turtle size, changed `.pencolor()` to `.color()`

Tested code here:

```
import turtle
from math import sqrt

SIZE_OF_TURTLE_COEFFICIENT = 0.255
def isPrime(n):
    if n < 2: return False
    if n == 2: return True
    if n % 2 == 0: return False
    k = 3
    while k < sqrt(n):
        if n % k == 0:
            return False
        k += 2
    return True

def plot(k):
    numPrimes = 0
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.color("green")
    turtle.shape('square')          # <-- added code starts here
    turtle.turtlesize(stretch_wid=SIZE_OF_TURTLE_COEFFICIENT, stretch_len=SIZE_OF_TURTLE_COEFFICIENT)
    turtle.stamp()
    n= 1
    dir = 1
    for i in range(80):
        for j in range(n):
            turtle.setx(turtle.xcor() + 7*dir)
            if isPrime(k):
                numPrimes += 1
                turtle.color("red")
            else:
                turtle.color("black")
            turtle.stamp()
            k += 1
        for j in range(n):
            turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() + 7*dir)
            if isPrime(k):
                turtle.color("red")
                numPrimes += 1
            else:
                turtle.color("black")
            turtle.stamp()
            k += 1
        n += 1
        dir = -dir
    print(k-1, numPrimes)
    turtle.hideturtle()

plot(1)
```

Comment: Yay! Yes, I was thinking of using the stamp() as well, but did not know how to make it do a square stamp. The Code proposed by you nailed it. Thanks!

Comment: You are very welcome